# Docker container exiting immediately after creation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I am trying to create multiple SQL server containers on a Linux host. The problem I face is that after I create the first container, every other created container after this just exits with a code 1. I am using the same Docker image I used for the very first container which has no issues what so ever. I am in a predicament at this moment and this is what `docker logs` show me.

The following was used to create the first docker container.

```
sudo docker container run -d -i -t \
--publish 1434:1433 \
--volume mssqlsystem:/var/opt/mssql \
--volume mssqluser:/var/opt/sqlserver \
--env ACCEPT_EULA=Y \
--env MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=**** \
--env MSSQL_DATA_DIR=/var/opt/sqlserver \
--env MSSQL_LOG_DIR=/var/opt/sqlserver \
--name sql2 \
 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
```

The following command was used to create the second container which has been exiting.

```
sudo docker container run -d -i -t \
--publish 1435:1433 \
--volume mssqlsystem:/var/opt/mssql \
--volume mssqluser:/var/opt/sqlserver \
--env ACCEPT_EULA=Y \
--env MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=**** \
--env MSSQL_DATA_DIR=/var/opt/sqlserver \
--env MSSQL_LOG_DIR=/var/opt/sqlserver \
--name sql3 \
 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
```

Docker logs show the following error for container 2:

```
*SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
2021-02-11 22:38:47.98 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'.
2021-02-11 22:38:48.10 Server      ERROR: Setup FAILED copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf':  2(The system cannot find the file specified.)
ERROR: BootstrapSystemDataDirectories() failure (HRESULT 0x80070002)
sqladmin@vmsqlubuntu01:~$ sudo docker logs -f 213fb583fd80
SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
2021-02-11 22:24:51.37 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'.
2021-02-11 22:24:51.50 Server      ERROR: Setup FAILED copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf':  2(The system cannot find the file specified.)*
```

What could be wrong here? The Linux host is a 8 GB memory and 2vCPU on Azure. This is a POC host so the configuration has been kept bare minimum. Will capping the memory of the first Docker host help in any way?

Comment: It is essential to be of any help, to add some information regarding the parameters used to run the 1st and the next docker images (the docker command). Please add more info to the question. Additionally try not to post images with text only and post the text itself.

Comment: I've added additional details as suggested. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps volume `mssqlsystem` can't be shared?

Comment: I actually had the same doubt and created some with bind mounts and the others with volumes.. they still exit immediately

Comment: Definitely. The volumes must not be shared.

Comment: @JoãoAlves thanks! your suggestion resolved the issue! :)